# PreferenceFragmentCompat not listening to first touch event

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I created a `PreferenceFragmentCompat` settings everything is working fine but I noticed something odd, clicking on setting button first time when preference screen loaded and I touch on some preference it does not respond to my first touch but right after it works normally this is my code

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements HomeActivity.Authentication, Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, ConfirmAlertDialog.OnDialogClickInterface {
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(final Preference preference) {
    final String key = preference.getKey();

    switch (key) {
        case "remove_ads":
            homeActivity.purchaseRemoveAds();
            break;
        case "hide_icon":
            try {
                homeActivity.loadFragment(new HideOptiosTutorial(), getParentFragment().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case "key_share_app_link":
            shareAppFile();

            break;

        case "move_to_sdcard":

            showMovetoSdDialog();

            break;
        case "button_internal":

            showMovetoInternalDialog();

            break;
        case "back_up_sdcard":
            if (isSDCardUnmounted()) {
                showSDCardMountError();
            } else {

                globalPasswords = getBackupPasswords();

                if (!FileUtilis.isSafAllowed(getActivity())) {
                    showSDCardNotAllowedDialog(983);
                    //
                    return false;
                }

                if (globalPasswords.size() == 0) {
                    showNoBackupFoundMsg();
                } else {
                    showDialogToBackupFromSDCard();
                }
            }
            break;
        case "change_password":
            showChangePinDialog();
            break;

        case "key_rate_us":
            rateApplication();
            break;
        case "app_link":
            SavedAlbumsFragment.showAppLockLink(getActivity());
            break;
        case "view_intruders":
            startActivity(new Intent(homeActivity, ViewIntruders.class));
            break;
        case "theme":
            showSelectTehmeDialog();
            break;

        case "enter_email":

            showChangeEmailDialog();
            break;
    }


    return false;
}
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers);
    Log.e("Mateen","onCreatePreferences");

    homeActivity = ((HomeActivity) getActivity());
    homeActivity.addAuthenticationListner(this);
    localDatabase = LocalDatabase.getInstance(getActivity());
    localPreferences = new LocalPreferences(getActivity());

    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(homeActivity).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("Remove_Is_Purchased"));

    removeAdsPref=findPreference("remove_ads");
    mCategory = (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("cat_remove_ads");



    if (localPreferences.IsRemovedAdsPurchased())
    {
        mCategory.removePreference(removeAdsPref);
        getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(mCategory);
    }
    else
    {
        removeAdsPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }

    findPreference("move_to_sdcard").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("view_intruders").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("button_internal").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("back_up_sdcard").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("change_password").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("key_rate_us").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("app_link").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("hide_icon").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("key_share_app_link").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("listPref_wrong_tries").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("theme").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("enter_email").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);




    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        findPreference("key_cam_short").setVisible(false);
        findPreference("key_vid_short").setVisible(false);
    }

    if (!PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(homeActivity).getBoolean("key_intruder_detection",false))
    {
        findPreference("listPref_wrong_tries").setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (!Reprint.isHardwarePresent()) {
        findPreference("key_fingerprint").setEnabled(false);
    }

    if (!FileUtilis.isSdcardPresent(getActivity())) {
        findPreference("move_to_sdcard").setEnabled(false);
        findPreference("button_internal").setEnabled(false);
        findPreference("back_up_sdcard").setEnabled(false);

        //  findPreference("change_password").setEnabled(false);
        findPreference("always_save_to_sdcard").setEnabled(false);
    }
    //add xml

}
```

and this is my preference xml:

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.andr]oid.com/apk/res-auto"
app:key="preferenceScreen">

<!-- These settings headers are only used on tablets. -->z
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory  android:title="@string/cate_remove_ads"
    android:key="cat_remove_ads">
    <Preference
        android:key="remove_ads"
        android:summary="@string/txt_remove_ads"
        android:title="@string/remove_ads" />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>

<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/storage">

    <Preference
        android:key="move_to_sdcard"
        android:summary="@string/export_sdcard_summary"
        android:title="@string/txt_move_to_external" />

    <Preference
        android:key="button_internal"
        android:summary="@string/export_internal_summary"
        android:title="@string/txt_move_too_internal" />

    <Preference
        android:key="back_up_sdcard"
        android:summary="@string/backup_summary"
        android:title="@string/back_from_sdcard" />

    <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="always_save_to_sdcard"
        android:summary="@string/always_on_sd_card"
        android:title="@string/sav_loc" />

</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>


<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/cate_security">


    <Preference
        android:key="hide_icon"
        android:title="@string/hide_icon" />


    <Preference
        android:key="app_link"
        android:summary="@string/app_link_title"
        android:title="@string/app_link_detail" />

    <Preference
        android:key="change_password"
        android:title="@string/chagne_password" />

    <Preference
        android:key="enter_email"
        android:title="@string/forgot_email_title"
        android:summary="@string/enter_email_to_recover" />


    <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="shuffle_pin"
        android:summary="@string/shuffle_summary"
        android:title="@string/shuffle_title" />

    <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="key_fingerprint"
        android:summary="@string/summary_fingerprint"
        android:title="@string/fingerprint_auth" />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>

<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/cate_intruder">
    <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="key_intruder_detection"
        android:summary="@string/take_intruder_picture_summary"
        android:title="@string/take_intruder_picture" />

    <android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="3"
        android:entries="@array/wrong_tries"
        android:entryValues="@array/wrong_tries"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:title="@string/wrong_tries"
        android:key="listPref_wrong_tries" />
    <Preference
        android:key="view_intruders"
        android:summary="@string/show_intruder_pic"
        android:title="@string/show_intruder_pic_summary" />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>

<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/cate_others">
    <Preference
        android:key="theme"
        android:summary="@string/chose_theme"
        android:title="@string/select_theme" />


    <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="key_cam_short"
        android:summary="@string/cam_short_detail"
        android:title="@string/sec_selfi_shortcut" />

    <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="key_vid_short"
        android:summary="@string/vid_short_detail"
        android:title="@string/sec_vid_shortcut" />

    <Preference
        android:key="key_share_app_link"
        android:summary="@string/share_app_link_detail"
        android:title="@string/share_app_link_title" />

    <Preference
        android:key="key_rate_us"
        android:summary="@string/rate_detail"
        android:title="@string/rate_us" />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
```

Please guide me what am I doing wrong? 
Is it support libs issue or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem by removing this line from my fragment layout's xml

```
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

from:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

now it is listening to my every damn touch :D Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be support library bug. It works as expected after updating app gradle dependencies to support library 27.0.0

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:27.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.0'
```

Comment: i updated all libs to '27.0.1' but facing the same issue :(